# How long do you cache resources client side?

Tags: caching, pragma

A website of mine will host the usual images, javascript and CSS stylesheets in the database. Since these are unlikely to change each day, I am going to use some client caching on these to reduce the server load.

How long do you cache these? A few days? More?

I'm probably not going to reuse the same name twice if I update the resource, so I shouldn't have outdated data concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing the name when you update, then you have the luxury of caching forever.  This is a big plus if you're okay with name changing.

It's also a good idea when it comes to script and CSS as some client machines will persist to cache even if you had ruled otherwise.

Comment: Is forever such a good practice? I mean that if everyone does the same thing it is a waste of client resources for not much benefit